# How can I automatically plot markers for addresses on a Google or OpenStreetMap?

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, openstreetmap

I have a list of UK addresses and would like to plot them on a google or openstreetmap (I dont mind which).

Is there a way to render a batch of addresses on a map with dots to represent the location (rather then the standard marker).

To make things slightly more complex, I would like to change the colour and size of some markers.

The data source is a street address including postcode and a marker type (size, color).

Does anyone know of a site, script, process to achieve this?

The geographic region will be a suburb so it is quite a small area.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Google Geocoding service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to spin through your addresses and translate them to latitude/longitude values that you can plot on a map.  You make HTTP requests to *http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode* to get back JSON (or XML) responses with the data you need.

Once you have geocoded all your addresses you can use the standard [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) to create render your locations as [markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers) on a map.  You can [customize](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#ComplexIcons) the look of your markers by specifying the appropriate options when you create your [google.maps.marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) objects.

Comment: your answer is awesome. A jsfiddle would be great if you already have a such code.